# Asp.net Core 5 .well-known serve up default.json file

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working a on service that needs to have a discovery .json file listed in a subdirectory of the well known folder. I would like for this .json file to be served up as a default file. However since it is a .json instead of a .htm or .html file the `app.UseDefaultFiles();` in my configure method does not work. Is it possible to serve up .json files as default files? I also have the `app.UseStaticFiles();` enabled.

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: You created the .well-known folder under wwwroot, and then created the json configuration file in it, and then you want to parse the configuration in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently, you can redirect a URL at a file

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path == "/.well-known/{subdirectory}")
    {
         context.Request.Path = "/.well-known/{subdirectory}/default.json";
    }
           
    await next();
});
```